# velocity smoother

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am working on my navigation project, where i am using turtlebot, Ubuntu 14.04 and ROS Indigo. Everything is working fine, but sometimes my robot does some jerky movements which i want to avoid. I came across velocity_smoother in ROS but i am not sure how i can use to make my robots' velocity smooth. How can i integrate it in my launch file or should i remap my velocity topics?

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks,
Sai Krishna Allani

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237805/velocity-smoother/) by [krishna43](https://answers.ros.org/users/22267/krishna43/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2016-06-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arwen](https://answers.ros.org/users/10946/arwen/) on 2016-07-15**:
I don't think you should be thinking about smoothing the velocity. The local planners already available provide acceleration control parameters that you can use in order to limit changes in the output velocity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It will not generate a very good result. But if you only want to implement, seems the velocity smoother wiki is quite clear... Try read through the page more carefully. If still no progress I can post my config file. http://wiki.ros.org/yocs_velocity_smoother

---

Originally posted by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) with karma: 710 on 2016-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0